# Vim plugin presenting a list of open tabs

Tags: vim, plugins, tabs, vim-plugins

I've looked around and couldn't seem to find what I need.

Basically, when I have many open tabs, it becomes difficult to realize what file is open in a specific tab.

Is there a plugin that would present a list of all open tabs?

Of course, there's :tabs but I'm looking for a plugin presenting a selectable list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This may be a solution to your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102384/using-vims-tabs-like-buffers/103590#103590) It encourages you to not use tabs and look at the more flexible buffer mechanism and use either MiniBufExpl or BufExplorer. Although not mentioned in the linked post, I would also suggest looking at [FuzzyFinder](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1984) which is quite good.

Comment: Is there a reason (besides the historical one) that one shouldn't ignore buffers completely and only work in tabs instead?

Comment: To answer my own question: perhaps the reason is many vim commands/functions/'usage procedures' (still) expect users to be working mostly with buffers for which reason it is better that users rely mainly on buffers. Thanks anyway for your link, very helpful.

Comment: @Andrei, yes I think it is mostly historical. Through the years much of the functionality of the buffers has been used and tested. The tabs seem to me like a misnomer, therefore users initially  expect something like Firefox or TextMate tabs and Vim's tabs are not well suited for this.

Comment: I don't think I'd be too mistaken when saying that those leading Vim development are themselves confused (to a certain degree at least) which only adds to the confusion of the users. Otherwise why put command options that make it easy to use tabs for some tasks (like vim -p file1 file2) etc.

Comment: @Andrei: I have never felt there was any confusion. Tabs have their place, but not as you are using them. Tabs are not used to compartmentalize different buffers. Tabs are used to present different organizations of windows (splits), each of which represents a view into a buffer. Thus tabs compartmentalize different sets of views onto a set of buffers. So, there is no reason to ignore tabs if you want to use them. But you need to use them correctly. And the commands and options such as the one you cite as an example are there to support this correct usage of tabs.

Answer (score 27):

You can use `:tabs`, If you tab 7 is the tab you want to go to then type `7gt`. If tab 2 is the tab you want to go to type `2gt`.

Comment: I just went to upvote this only to realize that I am the one who answered it almost a year ago.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer to this question is the first part of @Drew LeSueur

Use `:tabs`

I may correct the second part:

to go to a specific tab do `:tabn 7` or `:tabn7` not `:7gt`